# Rails number_field_tag pass hash value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am confused about setting the form name and its params.

Here is my form

```
<%= form_tag('/monster) do %>
  <% @monsters.each do |monster| %>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><%= monster.id %></th>
      <td><%= t("backpack.mon_infos.#{monster.name}.name") %></td>                
      <td><%= number_field_tag "monster[[#{monster.id},#{monster.name}]]", 0 %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The params will get this

```
"monster" => {
  "1,MonsterA" => "10",
  "2,MonsterB" => "25"
}
```

But I want it to be like

```
"monster" => {
  "1" => {'name': 'MonsterA' ,'quanty': "10"},
  "2" => {'name': 'MonsterB' ,'quanty': "25"}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
<%= form_tag('/monster) do %>
  <% @monsters.each do |monster| %>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><%= monster.id %></th>
      <td><%= t("backpack.mon_infos.#{monster.name}.name") %></td>                
      <%= hidden_field_tag "monster[#{monster.id}][name]", monster.name %>
      <td><%= number_field_tag "monster[#{monster.id}][quantity]", 0 %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Break up the values of `id` and `name` into their own `[id][name]`. To get the 2nd level hash, create the second key and map it to the value.

```
<% @monsters.each do |monster| %>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row"><%= monster.id %></th>
    <td><%= t("backpack.mon_infos.#{monster.name}.name") %></td>
    <td><%= number_field_tag "monster[#{monster.id}]['name']", monster.name %></td>
    <td><%= number_field_tag "monster[#{monster.id}]['quanty']", monster.quanty %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It's close, but it become `"monster" => {"1" => {"MonsterA" => "10"},"2" => {"MonsterB" => "25"}`.

Comment: Updated mine, but realized you probably don't want to show part of the value. Which may mean you want to go with @JagdeepSingh answer.